# Java not able to find image for splashscreen

Tags: java, swing

I have checked multiple posts about why my i'm getting a error saying that there is a NullPointerException at this line

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image.png")));
```

Every posts saying that its because it can't find the image. I have tried changing the code to absolute which does not change anything. I have moved the image into the src folder and the package for the program but nothing seems to work. Right now the image is in the src folder if that helps with someone solving why it does not work
Here is the Error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Then it points to that line of code.

Comment: See [Loading Images Using Get Resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource). Make sure your directlory is on your class path and you follow the examples in the link.

Comment: It is `image.png` not `Image.png` or `image.PNG` or..? `getResource` is case sensitive. Are you certain it is being included in the Jar? Check that it is. The easiest way (on Windows) is to rename the `.jar` to a `.zip` and double click it.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getResource()` call is returning `null` (which you're not checking) and  you're then getting the `NullPointerException`.

When you use `getResource()` it looks for the file in the same directory as the class -- including the package. So if this is in a `com.example` package, it'll need to be in `com/example/image.png`.

If the file is at the root of the classes directory or jar file, then you need to prefix it with `/`:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image.png")));
```

Comment: Ya I have seen this before and tried doing /image.png and still gives me the same errors for some reason

Comment: Check to see if image.png actually exists in the same directory as the classes (not the source files) of where you are running the application.

Comment: I checked the bin which has all the class files and it did not have the image.png in the directory, so should I add it manually,or do you mean the java file in my package cause if I import the image.png it appears in the package.

Comment: You'll need to set up whatever build tool or IDE you're using so that the image.png is copied from where you have it into the `bin` directory so that it is next to the class, as otherwise your getResource is always going to return null.

Comment: So I got it where now i'm seeing it appear in the bin file I still get a error with it saying that line but now its illegalArgumentException which looks like its for something else about JLabel but still shows that its that line of code where I use getResource().

Comment: It’s probably now loading the resources from the file system but the png you are loading isn’t a valid image format for the `ImageIcon`. To debug further, try splitting the line up into several so you can confirm this.